# My Ubuntu install CD wrote over entire Mac OS X. How Can I get OS X back?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uninstall, mac, data-recovery

so I decided to try out Ubuntu and burned the install CD. I went through the menu process, and chose a 20gb partition to install Ubuntu on.

Without warning or further confirmations, the Ubuntu install proceeded to wipe my entire harddrive. I lost everything on my iMac (Not the end of the world as i have a back up). My main problem is that I don't have a way to reinstall Mac Os X with my original install CD because Ubuntu reformated my entire drive and the computer doesn't recognise the Mac install cd, it just boots automatically in Ubuntu.

After looking online,i tried to see if could download Gparted and see if i could create a partition that would let my computer recognise my install cd. Right now I am creating a Mac OS Install USB drive to see if that helps.

I am really at a loss and would really appreciate ANY HELP or tips or anything to get my mac back on OS X.

Comment: Put the Mac install disk in and hold "c" on the keyboard while turning on the computer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you will be able to get OS X without wiping off ubuntu, installing OS X again and then try again without hopefully loosing OS X.

Are you able to hold the option/alt key when booting your iMac to get the boot loader or is that completely gone?

If you can boot from your USB / CD by holding ALT when booting you might be able to use the disk utility to resize the partition and install OS X that way.

Not sure if any of this helps...?

Tim